# Exit XNA Game in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna

I am working on XNA (Mono) game in Windows Phone 8. Once player dead, I need to exit the game and navigate to another XAML page. I tried game.Exit();. But it is exiting the entire application. Is this the actual behavior of Exit method in XNA game?

Or am i supposed to use any other way to exit a game?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new page to your project and navigate to it using NavigationService:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageName.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Your new page doesn't have to be an XNA page- you can mix those with "normal" Windows Phone Pages and use built-in controls.

Comment: This means, the game will be disposed?